# Mocking Jasmine Promises

Tags: javascript, angularjs, unit-testing, jasmine, promise

I am trying to write jasmine unit tests to test angular controllers and am running into issues where a service has been injected and is returning a promise.

I have a service which retrieves data from a server:

```
app.factory('LookupService', ['$resource', '$http', '$cookies',
function ($resource, userId) {
    return $resource('./Controller/GetFunction', {}, {
        query: { method: 'GET', params: { userId: userId }, isArray: true }
    });
}]);
```

Which is called in the controller:

```
$scope.returnedDataStore = lookupService.get({ userId: $scope.userId });
$scope.returnedDataStore.$promise.then(function (result) {
    $scope.processData(result.data);
});
```

In my unit tests I am injecting this service as below:

```
beforeEach(function () {
    module('app');

    lookupService = jasmine.createSpyObj('LookupService', ['get']);

    inject(function ($rootScope, $controller, $q) {
        $scope = $rootScope.$new();

        var deferred = $q.defer();
        lookupService.get.and.returnValue(deferred.promise);

        ctrl = $controller('myController', {
            $scope: $scope,
            LookUpService: lookupService
        });
    });
});
```

However, when the service is called in the controller, I am receiving an error that indicates that `$scope.returnedDataStore.$promise` is undefined:

> Cannot read property 'then' of undefined

I've searched a lot to try to resolve this issue but I'm not having much luck.

I'd be very appreciative if someone could point me in the right direction!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I generally do is -

Handle promise in service and return promise object to controller, see if its helpful for you:

```
describe('Controller: mainCtrl', function() {
    beforeEach(module('myApp'));

    var mainCtrl,
        scope,
        someService,
        spyGetSomething;


    beforeEach(inject(function($controller, $rootScope) {
        someService = {
            getSomething: function() {}
        };

        spyGetSomething = spyOn(someService, 'getSomething').andReturn({
            then: function() {}
        });

        mainCtrl = $controller('mainCtrl', {
            $scope: scope,
            SomeService: someService
        });
    });
    ... 

    it('Should call SomeService.getSomething() ', function() {
        expect(spyGetSomething).toHaveBeenCalled();
    });


});
```

(note: didn't test it)

Comment: Thank you! I've managed to get it working by mocking the promise object as you have above. For future reference my code now reads:
lookupService.get.and.returnValue({
    $promise:
    {
     then: function() {
      
     }
    }
   });